# Why is my CSS animation skipped when using classes and JavaScript to add elements to the class

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

This is my first time using CSS animation and what I'm trying to achieve is to have this title bar to shrink out of the way of a sidebar from 100% of the width of the screen (100vw) to 75vw. I'm running this in vanilla CSS and JavaScript, there are only two divs under the body in HTML (topDiv and sidebarDiv) and the issue that I'm facing is that the title bar shrinking animation is not running, the sidebar animation works fine.

The effect that should be achieved is that the sidebar 'pushes' the top title bar out of the way when the menubutton (on the title bar) is clicked. The issue I'm encountering is that the animation does not run and that there is a space between the title bar and sidebar until the sidebar finishes its animation and fills in the space between the title bar and the sidebar. Here's my CSS and JavaScript code:

```js
var sidebarClickedCounter = 0;
var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebarDiv");
var titleBar = document.getElementById("topDiv");
var sidebarOpen = false;

function openSideMenu(){
    // false = open, true = close  
    if(sidebarClickedCounter % 2){
        console.log("Close sidebar command.")
        sidebar.classList.remove("animatedSidebar");
        titleBar.classList.remove("shrinkTopBar");
        sidebar.style.display = "none";

        titleBar.style.width = "100vw";
        sidebarOpen = false;
    } else {
        console.log("open sidebar command.")
        sidebar.style.display = "flex";
        sidebar.classList.add("animatedSidebar");
        titleBar.classList.add("shrinkTopBar");

        sidebar.style.transform = "translate(0%, 0%)";
        titleBar.style.width = "75vw";
        sidebarOpen = true;
    }
    sidebarClickedCounter++;
}
```

```css
@keyframes openingSidebar {
  from{transform: translateX(-100%);}
  to{transform: translateX(0%);}
}

@keyframes openingSidebarTitle {
  from{width:100vw;}
  to{width:75vw;}
}

body {
  display:flex;
}

#topDiv {
  background-color: #A167A5;
  height:6vw;
  width:100vw;
}

#textContainer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  height: 5vw;
}

.sidebar {
  display:none;
  background-color:#A167A5;
  color:#E8D7F1;
  height:100vw;
  width: 20vw;
  overflow:hidden;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  padding-left:2.5vw;
  padding-right:3vw;
}

.animatedSidebar {
  animation-name: openingSidebar;
  animation-duration:1s;
  animation-timing-function:linear;
}

.shrinkTopBar {
  animation-name:openingSidebarTitle;
  animation-duration:1s;
  animation-timing-function:linear;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebarDiv" class="sidebar">
    <div class="textSidebarContainer">
        <h4>ABOUT US</h4>
        <h4>SPONSORS</h4>
        <h4>SPONSORS</h4>
        <h4>DOCUMENTATION</h4>
        <h4>CONTACT US</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- <div id="mainBody" class="mainBody"> -->
<div id="topDiv">
    <span id="textContainer">
        <button onclick="openSideMenu()" id="menuButton"> 
        </button>
        <h1 id="Title">Title text</h1>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: It would help if you also proved the html layout and even could post it on codepen or similar service.

Comment: @Kris.K SO asks that code be posted direct in the question as external sites can disappear. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: https://codepen.io/George-Soryal/pen/BabGoRg

Comment: You may like to investigate using forwards in the animation setting rather than setting final width in JS.

Comment: @AHaworth your link doesn't provide any info about prohibiting posting your code somewhere else? SO doesn't demand it. In fact many, people on SO do that, and noone bans them for that.

Comment: @Kris.K the link I gave was to show how to create an example. For a direct request not to rely on external links see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use position absolute together with the left property.You also need to use animation-fill-mode: forwards; to stop animation at the last step (not go back at initial point. I also added the word button in your button to be seen better

```js
var sidebarClickedCounter = 0;
var sidebar = document.getElementById("sidebarDiv");
var titleBar = document.getElementById("topDiv");
var sidebarOpen = false;

function openSideMenu(){
    // false = open, true = close  
    if(sidebarClickedCounter % 2){
        console.log("Close sidebar command.")
        sidebar.classList.remove("animatedSidebar");
        titleBar.classList.remove("shrinkTopBar");
        sidebar.style.display = "none";

        titleBar.style.width = "100vw";
        sidebarOpen = false;
    } else {
        console.log("open sidebar command.")
        sidebar.style.display = "flex";
        sidebar.classList.add("animatedSidebar");
        titleBar.classList.add("shrinkTopBar");

        sidebar.style.transform = "translate(0%, 0%)";
        titleBar.style.width = "75vw";
        sidebarOpen = true;
    }
    sidebarClickedCounter++;
}
```

```css
@keyframes openingSidebar {
  from{
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to{
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

@keyframes openingSidebarTitle {
  from{
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
  }
  to{
    left: 25%;
    width: 75%;
  }

}

body {
  position: relative;
  display:flex;
}

#topDiv {
  background-color: #A167A5;
  height:6vw;
  width:100vw;
}

#textContainer{
  display: flex;
  justify-content: left;
  align-items: center;
  height: 5vw;
}

.sidebar {
  display:none;
  background-color:#A167A5;
  color:#E8D7F1;
  height:100vw;
  width: 20vw;
  overflow:hidden;
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  padding-left:2.5vw;
  padding-right:3vw;
}

.animatedSidebar {
  animation-name: openingSidebar;
  animation-duration:1s;
  animation-timing-function:linear;

}

.shrinkTopBar {
  position: absolute;
  animation-name:openingSidebarTitle;
  animation-duration:1s;
  animation-timing-function:linear;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebarDiv" class="sidebar">
    <div class="textSidebarContainer">
        <h4>ABOUT US</h4>
        <h4>SPONSORS</h4>
        <h4>SPONSORS</h4>
        <h4>DOCUMENTATION</h4>
        <h4>CONTACT US</h4>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- <div id="mainBody" class="mainBody"> -->
<div id="topDiv">
    <span id="textContainer">
        <button onclick="openSideMenu()" id="menuButton"> button
        </button>
        <h1 id="Title">Title text</h1>
    </span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, this works. I did not realize there was a way to "toggle" these CSS animations with forwards.

Comment: Great and happy that this helped you. There are many others interesting properties with animation that you can check reverse alternate..